# htaccess retorna $i

Tags: php, htaccess

Boa noite, fiz um código htacces assim:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^app/([0-9]+) app.php?id=$i
```

A primeira rule é pra tirar o ".php" das paginas e a segunda é pra que ao inves de aparecer app.php?id=11 apareça app/11, porém quando faço o $_GET["id"]; ele retorna "$i" que é a variavel do htaccess, alguem sabe a solução pra que ele retorno o valor do id, no caso, estou usando ids alfanumericos, por exemplo: 09a6cc

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: No caso creio que para capturar o primeiro grupo da regex, seria $1 e não $i

Answer (score 1):

Troque para isso:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^app/(.*)$ app.php?id=$1
```

No caso, você colocou $i ao invés de $1.
E também, este permite alfanuméricos.

Comment: Funcionou, mas as páginas que estão sem o .php pararam de funcionar, acredito que o código RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php seja pra fazer isso, mas aqui não funcionou, sabe me dizer porque?

Comment: E usando exatamente o seu código sem alterar, ele retorna no $_GET["id"] isso: 18ceb3.php/18ceb3, sendo que o 18ceb3 é o id da url.

Comment: Alterei minha resposta. Sem querer tinha colocado pra reescrever também a página. Tente agora

Comment: Sem querer ser chato, mas já sendo, tipo, você está ajudando muito, mas agora com essa correção que fez, os link sem o .php funcionam, mas no app, fazendo o $_GET["id"] ele retorna o id da página junto com .php Exemplo: e1d166.php sendo e1d166 o id da página.